# OpenCV OMX artifacts

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I'm using hardware encoding via FFMPEG and OpenMAX.

If I'm using FFmpeg h264_omx as a backend for VideoWriter than I get image [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Kg8.jpg). Colors obviously kind of mixed.

Other codecs work fine. If I'll just re-encode via the FFMpeg command line, the output will be okay.

What is the workaround and where should I look?

- Machine: Raspberry Pi 4B+
- System: Custom Yocto Distribution (master branches)
- OpenCV version: 4.1.0
- FFMpeg version: 4.2.2 (build with --enable-omx and --enable-omx-rpi)

Comment: How can we duplicate this issue?

Comment: @llogan how this is a duplicate, different technologies.

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question is currently too broad to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with encoding h264 through rtmp...
I believe this is a pixel padding/alignment issue, but I do not know where the issue arises.

Comment: To increase the value of your answer my suggestion is to explain a little bit more how you came to the conclusion it might be a pixel padding/alignment issue. Atm. its a rep issue not being a comment. EoR.